# indexing embedded field

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which contain fields like above:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55545754754575775757"),
    "ref" : 161,
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-06T17:37:23.786Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-04T16:57:41.257Z"),
    "place" : {
        "html_attributions" : [],
        "vicinity" : "Paris",
        "utc_offset" : 120,
        "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?q=Paris,+France&ftid=0x47e66e1f06e2b70f:0x40b82c3688c9460",
        "types" : [ 
            "locality", 
            "political"
        ],
        "scope" : "GOOGLE",
        "reference" : "CmRbAAAA_URStRniv8M-nCXl79L6zwf_DUcDwtt7L6DrY0_ZTf3Wkq4tmtZ7dYVod5dmzuwRfSCNWvZG8ey71D6ooNGgqoPadVCqf9tlNMIKe209blvIeAOE92wDZ_Oj-_uEv9i2EhDyXVuaeQQrVqWaNdY6jfcWGhRrdJvHfm_vQPpd-Hb7rBOMszo1xA",
        "place_id" : "ChIJD7fiBh9u5kcRYJSMaMOCCwQ",
        "name" : "Paris",
        "id" : "691b237b0322f28988f3ce03e321ff72a12167fd",
        "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
        "geometry" : {
            "viewport" : {
                "east" : 2.46992079999995,
                "north" : 48.9021449,
                "west" : 2.22519299999999,
                "south" : 48.815573
            },
            "location" : {
                "lng" : 2.35222190000002,
                "lat" : 48.856614
            }
        },
        "formatted_address" : "Paris, France",
        "adr_address" : "<span class=\"locality\">Paris</span>, <span class=\"country-name\">France</span>",      
    "description" : "Le MacBook Pro doté de la révolutionnaire Touch Bar est disponible en modèles 13 et 15 pouces. ... Vérifier la disponibilité MacBook Pro 13 pouces - Gris sidéral ..... Les prix comprennent la TVA (20 %) et la taxe sur les primes d'assurance",
    "prix" : 1.499,
    "titre" : "macbook pro",
    "premium_test" : false,
    "premium" : {
        "statut" : false
    },
    "etatProduit" : [ 
        ObjectId("578372bf092521281c913af8")
    ],
    "departement" : [],
    "sous_categorie" : [ 
        ObjectId("57aae8781149cd000751436c")
    ],
    "user_id" : [ 
        ObjectId("575fda6a485328b0194a0a8a")
    ],
    "media_type" : [ 
        ObjectId("57975f7b6b6f9224115ce691")
    ],
    "media" : [ 
        "file-1499187461324.png", 
        "file-1499187535058.jpg"
    ],
    "pointure" : 0,
    "capacite" : 0,
    "piscine" : false,
    "nombre_pieces" : 0
   
}
```

I need to know how I can create an index on the field: "formatted_address" which is in an array of subdocuments. I added this code:

```
annonceSchema.index({ place :'text' });
```

The query is:  `db.annonce.find({$text : {$search : 'Paris, France'}});`

Comment: It's not an array field. And the simple path is `{ "place.formatted_address": "text" } )` with the "dot" `.` and the quotes `""`.